# What size pocket hole screw for 1.5x1.5 miter?

Tags: woodworking, joinery, miter

Im making a headboard framed with 1.5x1.5" pine. The joints at the top are mitered. What size screw should I use for pocket holes?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer was a simple web-search away.

Answer (score 1):

The size of pocket hole  screws are **determined by the thickness of the wood or material you are joining** not by the type of joinery. *I.E. butt joint or miter joint*.

There is a guide that comes with the [kreg system](https://www.kregtool.com/about-us/news/kreg-tool-tips-joining/choose-the-correct-screw-length.aspx) that will tell what size screw you need for the **thickness** of wood you are working with. (*You do not say if your wood is 1.5 thick or 1.5 wide, it is the thickness that matters*)

**Note:** *There are other pocket-hole screw systems, this happens to be the one i purchased.*

For 1 1/2" material it is a 2 1/2" screw

[image: screw guide]

Comment: Ok I have kreg too. Im using 2 1/2 screws. I drilled the pocket perpendicular. As I drill the screw in, it pushes the other piece out of place.

Comment: @riotburn "How do I fix my screwed together joint where the screw pushed the wood apart?" would make an excellent question of its own.

Comment: @riotburn We can not tell you what you are doing wrong as we do not know how/what you  are doing. There are instructions that come with the Kreg unit that tell you how to set up your jig AND how to set the depth/stop collar of the dill bit. And how to clamp your work pieces.  All these settings must be appropriate for the thickness  of your wood and the screws you are using. If you do not know and do not have the instructions then search YouTube, you will find the answers there.

Comment: You need to clamp the boards together at the ends to keep the boards from shifting.  Your use of a miterd (angle) joint compounded the shifting.

Comment: Also 2 1/2" does not seem correct if your pocket hole is on the same angle as the miter as I see that the screw would be too long.